# How to create a Drop Down list from a Table WITHOUT using INDIRECT function

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm currently making a new spread sheet and I need to create a drop down list of all the entries in a column in a table. And up to now, I've always used the formula INDIRECT("Table1[Column1]") in the Data Validation.

However, I've heard that the INDIRECT function is volatile and must be avoided. I tried to make a formula using INDEX and MATCH, but for whatever reason, I can't seem to make it work in the Data Validation.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting method, I'd never considered using INDIRECT in that way - I will have to try yours sometime to see what it's like.

You could create a named range and refine using Name Manager, then use the Data Validation to refer directly to the named range. For example:

Name: ListEmployees
Refers to: Table1[Column1]

So you would end up with:

[image: Data Validation Window for Named Ranges]

Comment: Oh my goodness, I just figured out you could do that. I always thought names in Excel were for only Tables. Didn't know you could make custom range names for columns that are part of a table. Thanks!